# html button is not loading document.location on click

Tags: html, css, browser, codepen

I have a problem, when i click run in visiual studio and then i click the button 
"  [ https://www.coursera.org/learn/duke-programming-web][1] Programming Foundations with JavaScript, HTML and CSS

will the corsera website open. But when i make this in codepen.io for coding,that i click the button, then the website can not open.

Why happend that? `

if i click on the button of visiual studio then the corsera website will open, but if i do that from the website for coding, then corsera will reject it, so the website won't open?

```
    <html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Curriculum Vitae</title>
  </head>

  <body>

      <em><h1><b><p>Curriculum Vitae:</p></b></h1></em>

    <br>
    <div>
         <h3>Photo:</h3>
        <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*l2AFc33U7grIeMML0a0unQ.jpeg"                   width="200px" height="150px">

   </div> 
   <div> 
       <h3><p>Contact details:</p></h3>
     <ul> 

       <li><h4>Name: &nbsp Alex Alex </h4></li>
       <li><h4>Email: &nbsp example@gmail.com</h4></li>
       <li><h4>Mobile number: &nbsp 005910280000</h4></li>
    </ul>  
      <hr>
      <b><h3>Education:</h3></b>
    <ol start="10">
      <li><h4> 2011-2014 &nbsp University education</li>
      <li><h4> 2008-2011 &nbsp high school </h4></li>
      <li><h4> 2005-2008 &nbsp Secondary education</h4></li>
      <li><h4> 2000-2005 &nbsp the basic education</h4></li>
    </ol>
    <hr>
   </div>  
   <div> 

      <em>Notes:</em>
     <div>      
      <p>For more cv you should to visit this <a href="https://www.myperfectcv.co.uk/cv-examples/simple-cv-sample" target="_parent">cv-website </a></p>
     </div>
    <div>
      for more hacks photos cklic the photo
      <a href="https://www.shutterstock.com/search/website%2Bhack" target="_Parent">
      <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/computer-hacker-cyber-attack-concept-600w-553688845.jpg" alt="Hack Photo" width="25" height="25">
      </a>
     </div> 

   </div> 

  <h2>Button as link</h2>
    <p> click the button to see corsera website</p>
    <button onclick=" document.location='https://www.coursera.org/learn/duke-programming-web'"> Programming Foundations with JavaScript, HTML and CSS</button>

  </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

CodePen will render your HTML page within an iFrame.

Some sites will try to block that.

Other links to other sites will work.

Try like a Wikipedia link, for example:

```
 <button onclick="document.location='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intentionally_blank_page'"> Programming Foundations
        with JavaScript, HTML and CSS</button>
```

It's not your code issue, it's because of codepen. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @foreza's response, the link is working but the site is blocked because of Cross-Origin request sharing (CORS) which you can read about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

In codepen, you're trying to request a site from a different origin and that site blocks cross origin requests.
A site that doesn't block cross origin requests, like wikipedia, will work
or
A site with the same origin (codepen in this case) will also work.
In a codepen:

```html
<button onclick="javascript:document.location='https://codepen.io/gpspake/pen/NWGevvj'"> Programming Foundations with JavaScript, HTML and CSS</button>
```

Example: https://codepen.io/gpspake/pen/NWGevvj

In codepen, right click and click inspect to open your browser's developer tools, then click on the network tab to see the requests that are being sent when you click the button.